# GLSL shader to support coloring and texturing

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

Im trying to write a shader that support both color and texture.
For some reason I can make it work.
No errors threw and each of them work perfect separately,

get location:

```
shaderProgram.useTextureUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uUseTexture");
```

when drawing I change the value like this:

```
    var uUseTexture=false;
    gl.uniform1f(shaderProgram.useTextureUniform, uUseTexture);
```

And the GLSL itself:

fragment:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;
uniform bool uUseTexture;
void main(void) {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    vec4 texColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a);
    vec4 vertexColor = vColor; 
    if (!uUseTexture){
        gl_FragColor = vertexColor;
    }
    else{
        gl_FragColor = texColor; 
    }
}
```

vertex:

```
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec4 vColor;


    void main(void){
        vec4 mvPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * mvPosition;
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        vColor = aVertexColor;}
```

Comment: What it looks like when thinks go wrong? *gl_FragColor = mix(texColor, vertexColor, 0.5);*?

Comment: @PauliNieminen - texture not work, only color

Comment: Right. I didn't understand your original question completely. Shaders look fine to me. Texture sampling failing to read values sounds like texture isn't bound to unit or uSampler or vTextureCoord isn't setup correctly to propagate from javascript/vbo to fragment shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I tell you how to make your shader work you arguably should not do it that way. You should either

1. Make 2 shaders

   Make one shader that uses a texture and a different shader that uses vertex colors. This is what nearly all professional game engines would do.
2. Make a shader that multiplies both colors and set one to white

   If you have

   ```
   gl_FragColor = vertexColor * textureColor;
   ```

   Then if `textureColor` is `1,1,1,1` that means you're multiplying by 1 
   and so the result is just `vertexColor`. Similarly if `vertexColor`
   is `1,1,1,1` then you're multiplying by 1 and so the result is just
   `textureColor`

   You can get a white texture by making just a single pixel white texture

   ```
   var tex = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA,
                 gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([255, 255, 255, 255]));
   ```

   Then anytime you just want vertex colors bind that texture to a texture
   unit and tell the sampler which unit it you put it in

   You might also want to turn off texture coordinates

   ```
   gl.disableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
   ```

   When you want just texture color then you can do this

   ```
   // turn off the attribute
   gl.disableVertexAttribArray(aVertexColorLocation);

   // set the attribute's constant value
   gl.vertexAttrib4f(aVertexColorLocation, 1, 1, 1, 1);
   ```

   This method has the added benefit that you can also use both texture colors and vertex colors together to modify the texture color or to tint the texture color. Many game engines would do this as well specifically to take advantage of that ability to blend the colors.
3. Pauli mentions another option which is to use mix

   ```
   uniform float u_mixAmount;

   gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, vertexColor, u_mixAmount);
   ```

   This would also work as you can set `u_mixAmount` to 0.0 when you want
   `textureColor` and to 1.0 when you want `vertexColor` but unlike your
   boolean example you can also fade between the 2 colors with values
   between 0.0 and 1.0.  For example 0.3 is 30% of `vertexColor` and 70%
   of `textureColor`

A few other things

This line

```
vec4 texColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a);
```

Is no different than

```
vec4 texColor = textureColor;
```

Just trying your shader it seems to work as is which suggests the issue is not your shader but some other part of your code.

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var m4 = twgl.m4;

var arrays = {
  aVertexPosition: [
    -1, -1, 0,
     1, -1, 0,
    -1,  1, 0,
     1,  1, 0,
  ],
  aVertexNormal: [
     0,  0,  1,
     0,  0,  1,
     0,  0,  1,
     0,  0,  1,
  ],
  aTextureCoord: [
     0,  0, 
     1,  0,
     0,  1,
     1,  1,
  ],
  aVertexColor: [
     1, 0, 0, 1,
     0, 1, 0, 1,
     0, 0, 1, 1,
     1, 0, 1, 1,
  ],
  indices: [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3,
  ],
};
    
var tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  format: gl.LUMINANCE,
  mag: gl.NEAREST,
  src: [224, 64, 128, 192],
});
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ['vs', 'fs']);
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    uMVMatrix: m4.identity(),
    uPMatrix: m4.scale(m4.translation([i === 0 ? -0.5 : 0.5, 0, 0]), [0.5, 1, 1]),
    uNMatrix: m4.identity(),
    uSampler: tex,
    uUseTexture: i === 1,
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script id="fs" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;
uniform bool uUseTexture;
void main(void) {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    vec4 texColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a);
    vec4 vertexColor = vColor; 
    if (!uUseTexture){
        gl_FragColor = vertexColor;
    }
    else{
        gl_FragColor = texColor; 
    }
}
</script>
<script id="vs" type="not-js">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying vec4 vColor;


    void main(void){
        vec4 mvPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * mvPosition;
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        vColor = aVertexColor;}
</script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this great answer.
anyway - tried what pauli said and I get only the color part, can't understand why.

Comment: as you said maybe its a bug somewhere in the program

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console for errors? If your texture is setup wrong then it will just be 0,0,0,0 so you won't see a texture. Do you at least **not** see the vertex colors when you set `uUseTexture` to `true`?

Comment: I added gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
before using texture.